# UIScrollView not scroll in Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a .xib file containing an empty view and scrollview, below is the code that pulls the scrollview into the main view, the problem is that the scroll does not work:

```
@property (atomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scroll;

@synthesize scroll;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scroll];
}
```

I realized quite looking around this forum, and on google, but none of them solved my problem, just in case I am providing my project to donwload with the hope that someone visualize the problem: [ScrollView Example Download](http://www.4shared.com/zip/AvmL0-WJce/ScrollViewExample.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Departamento B mentionned, adding your scrollView a new time to your main view is not really necessary so you should delete this row.

Basically, `UIScrollView`component need 2 assets of parameters to control its scroll:

- Its own frame

You can control this frame with your `.xib` file by adjusting it in `Size inspector`, or you can do it programmatically with such kind of code:

> UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)].

- The frame of its content

You should adjust the frame of its content to be sure it will be scrollable, basically you should use this method:

> scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 200);

In this case, your `scrollView` would scroll vertically since its height's content is bigger than its height's frame.

***SAMPLE WITH YOUR CODE***

```
@property (atomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scroll;

@synthesize scroll;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Readjust your scroll frame
    self.scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    // Set its content size
    self.scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * 2);

    // The following method is not necessary
    // [self.view addSubview:self.scroll];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the UIScrollView in the .xib it should already be there.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.scroll];
```

is not necessary.

The view inside your scrollview should be bigger than the scrollview to actually scroll. Try putting some static UILabel with text inside it to test the basic scrolling works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the scroll view what it's size is and what the content in the view is.

In your case, this is how you could proceed :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scroll.contentSize = self.scroll.bounds.size; // The content size
    self.scroll.frame = self.view.frame; // The view size
    [self.view addSubview:self.scroll];
}
```

This is surely not the best way to do it but I just put this code so you can understand the use of "contentSize".

If you have any other question on UIScrollView, use this page. This is where I found the answer : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

.